# Empty object with union type in graphQL

Tags: express, graphql

When I' using union type in my graphQL schema I use it typically like this:

```
const documentTypeDefs = gql`
 union TestType = TypeExample1 | TypeExample2

 type Document {
   exampleKey: TestType
 }
`
```

Then I resolve it like this:

```
  TestType: {
    __resolveType(obj) {
     if(obj.property1) {
       return 'TypeExample1';
     }

     if(obj.property2) {
       return 'TypeExample2';
     }

    return null;
  },
}
```

But sometimes I'm getting empty object in my resolving function (ie. `obj` is `{}`). I thought returning `null` or `undefined` will do the job but unfortunately I'm getting error:

```
"Abstract type ItemsType must resolve to an Object type at runtime for field Document.exampleKey with value {}, received \"{}\". Either the ItemsType type should provide a \"resolveType\" function or each possible type should provide an \"isTypeOf\" function."
```

How can I resolve empty object then?
Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

If an empty object is being passed to `__resolveType`, that means your field is resolving to an empty object. That means either the value being returned inside your resolver is an empty object, or else the Promise returned is resolving to one.

If you're working with a field that returns a `List`, it's also possible for just one of the items being returned to be an empty object. This is particularly likely when working with MongoDB if one of the documents you're getting is actually empty or at least missing the fields you've specified in your `mongoose` schema.

Comment: Yes, the source of data I’m resolving consints of array of objects but few amongs them are just empty. Thus the data is constructed that way. But the thing is that graphql is comlaining about that inside resolveType function. I can cover that case of being empty object but cannot return an empty type because as far I understand there is none such a type available.

Comment: @Murakami my point was that an empty object here would normally indicate something else going amiss and addressing that issue would also resolve this one.

Comment: If, however, resolving to an empty object is expected behavior, you can either 1) default to one or the other if the object is empty; 2) add a third type to the union to cover the case when you're returning an empty type; or 3) pick a better way to distinguish between `TypeExample1` and `TypeExample2`. For example, if the object is an instance of a particular model, you can use `instanceof` to determine which type should be returned inside of `resolveType`.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Talking about option 2 is there a way to construct empty type, ie. with no key-property pair? I tried that with no success though

Comment: No, object types must have at least one field per the spec.